# Get data from Mac OS X Activity Monitor or Console to log hours worked on particular application

Tags: macos

I wanted to grab data from my desktop applications and display it on my website to show how much time I'm spending using a particular application. As a designer / developer it would be interesting to show how I split my time between developer applications, e.g Textmate, Coda, CSSEdit, and Design Applications, Photoshop, Illustrator etc. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wakoopa](http://social.wakoopa.com/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Many thanks. Looks perfect. Haven't had a chance to look at their documentation but I'm guessing I can dig in to their API instead of suing their proprietary widgets. Have you used them yourself?